# Is there a way to detect smooth video playback in GStreamer?

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer

I have a WebRTC connection in my application that I wont want to connect to the inbound elements until the video returning from it is smooth. I tend to get about 1 second of stuttering when I block the probe and then connect it afterward.

Ideally, I'd like to remove that stutter in favour of a delay. Is there an canonical way to do this in GStreamer?